# Normalized and anti-aliased Z pass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

In Blender Cycles a Z pass can be automatically normalized with a Normalize node.
A Mist pass is anti-aliased and have smooth shading.

**How to get automatically normalized and anti-aliased depth map?**

I tried the [method with Ray Length input](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52992/looking-for-a-usable-solution-for-z-pass-aliasing), normalizing works fine but I got an unsatisfied result with compositing — the thin gray background that I have to add to normalize the image:

[image]

The Mist pass can't be automatically normalized properly, because all the space behind the object is equal 1.

[image]

Or should I do it in the other proper way?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify how the mist pass isn't meeting your needs?

Comment: @JtheNinja thanks for your comment, I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally solve it.
The normalized mist pass node group with and without alpha mask:

[image]
[image]